# Center Only Specific Text

Tags: text-alignment, game-maker

I am trying to make it so that only one draw text item will be centered instead of all of them but i cant get it to work.  draw_set_halign(fa_center) changes all text but I am only looking to change one thing.  I know this is a simple question with pretty much no detail but I think it is still clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `draw_set_halign()` before each text.

```
draw_set_halign(fa_center);
draw_text(...);

draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_text(...);
draw_text(...);
```

If you want change one line (or just a part) of one text, then you need split text to independent parts and draw each one using correct halign.